# R diagonal network with regroupments (not only tree's separations)

Tags: r, networking, graph, networkd3

I've discovered the wonderful networkD3 package in R with which we can do this kind of htmlwidget.

```
 library('networkD3')
 library('data.tree')
 Relationships<- data.frame(Parent=c("earth","earth","forest","forest","ocean","ocean","ocean","ocean","fish","seaweed"),
                    Child=c("ocean","forest","tree","sasquatch","fish","seaweed","mantis shrimp","sea monster","fish&seaweed","fish&seaweed"))
 tree <- FromDataFrameNetwork(Relationships)
 tree <- ToListExplicit(tree, unname = TRUE)
 diagonalNetwork(tree)
```

[image]

However, i would like to do this kind of representation (regroupments instead of separation) in red and I don't find any way to do it in R because diagonalNetwork needs that we work with a tree (no regroupment).

I would like to keep the linear presentation. For exemple I do NOT want something like that...

```
 simpleNetwork(Relationships, fontFamily = "sans-serif",fontSize=10)
```

[image]

Do you have any solution for me ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a different graphical interface you could use the visNetwork package :

```
 library(visNetwork)
 nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                label = c("earth","ocean","forest","fish","seaweed","mantis shrimp","sea monster","tree","sasquatch", "fish seaweed"),
                level = c(1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4))
 edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,10,10),
                to = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,5))
 visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% 
     visNodes() %>% 
     visHierarchicalLayout(direction = "LR", levelSeparation = 500)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you AQLT. It is a good way to represent it. If there are possibilities to replace links with arrows it would be even better. I'll investigate.

Answer (score 2):

maybe a sankey plot is what you're looking for?

```
library('networkD3')

Links <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, text = "
Parent  Child
earth   ocean
earth   forest
forest  tree
forest  sasquatch
ocean   fish
ocean   seaweed
ocean   'mantis shrimp'
ocean   'sea monster'
fish    fish&seaweed
seaweed fish&seaweed
")

Nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(Links$Parent, Links$Child)))
Links$Parent <- match(Links$Parent, Nodes$name) - 1
Links$Child <- match(Links$Child, Nodes$name) - 1
Links$Value <- 1

sankeyNetwork(Links = Links, Nodes = Nodes, Source = "Parent", Target = "Child", 
              Value = "Value", NodeID = "name")
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, that's a solution which works ! Thank you. For my project, I would prefer the design of diagonalnetwork (smaller and thinner links and rectangles, no color...) but maybe it is possible to personnalize some parameters.